# Manipulating XML data through Flex

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am making a program that adds players to the stage and I can add or subtract points. I think I am close to completion except for a few things, I can't see my player names on the screen and I am having trouble displaying scores. The scores are being incremented and decremented when the buttons are clicked, but the display label is not displaying them. Here is my whole program right now. It is a little messy so I apologize in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"       applicationComplete="init()">
<fx:Style source="style.css.css"/>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <fx:XML id="playerData" source="data/data.xml" />
    <s:XMLListCollection id="playerList" source="{playerData.player}" />
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

    s|Button { color:#F2E9E9; }

    s|Label { color:#f2e9e9; }

    #outterBorder { backgroundColor:F7FEF9; }
</fx:Style>
<s:BorderContainer id="outterBorder" x="328" y="48" width="307" height="547">
    <s:Image x="269" y="10"/>
    <s:Label x="25" y="19" width="107" height="21" text="Score Keeper" color="#000000"/>
    <s:BorderContainer id="innerBorder" x="10" y="58" width="285" height="477">
        <s:TextInput id="myTextBox" x="10" y="425" width="138" />
        <s:Button id="add" x="176" y="425" width="97" label="Add Player" click="addPlayer()" />
        <s:HGroup id="group1" x="10" y="10" width="263" height="92" >
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup id="group2" x="10" y="114" width="264" height="92">
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup id="group3" x="10" y="214" width="263" height="92">
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup id="group4" x="10" y="313" width="263" height="92">
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:BorderContainer>

</s:BorderContainer>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        //Gabe Dougherty
        //n222
        //Midterm
        //3-8-13


        public var myPlayerLabel:Label = new Label;
        public var myScoreLabel:Label = new Label;
        public var myIncScore:Button = new Button;
        public var myDecScore:Button = new Button;
        public var myPlayerDelete:Button = new Button;
        public var myScore:Number = 0;
        public var numPlayers:Number = 0;

        public function init():void {
            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("newPlayer.xml");
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
            stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);

            var str:String = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);
            stream.close();

            playerData = XML(str);
            myPlayerLabel.text = playerData;

            //re-enable myDecScore
            myDecScore.enabled = true;

        }

        public function addPlayer():void {
            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("newPlayer.xml");

            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);


            var str:String = playerData.toString();

            stream.writeUTFBytes(str);
            stream.close(); 

            //set all player info
            //make playerLabel
            var playerLabel:Label = new Label();

            //make scoreLabel
            var scoreLabel:Label = new Label();
            scoreLabel.text = String(myScore);

            //make decScore
            var decScore:Button = new Button();
            decScore.label = "-";
            decScore.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, decrementScore);

            //make incScore
            var incScore:Button = new Button();
            incScore.label = "+"
            incScore.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, incrementScore);

            //make playerDelete
            var playerDelete:Button = new Button();
            playerDelete.label = "Delete";
            playerDelete.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deletePlayer);


            numPlayers++;
            if(numPlayers == 1) {

                group1.addElement(playerLabel);
                group1.addElement(scoreLabel);
                group1.addElement(decScore);
                group1.addElement(incScore);
                group1.addElement(playerDelete);
            } else if(numPlayers == 2) {

                group2.addElement(playerLabel);
                group2.addElement(scoreLabel);
                group2.addElement(decScore);
                group2.addElement(incScore);
                group2.addElement(playerDelete);
            } else if(numPlayers == 3) {

                group3.addElement(playerLabel);
                group3.addElement(scoreLabel);
                group3.addElement(decScore);
                group3.addElement(incScore);
                group3.addElement(playerDelete);;
            } else if(numPlayers == 4) {

                group4.addElement(playerLabel);
                group4.addElement(scoreLabel);
                group4.addElement(decScore);
                group4.addElement(incScore);
                group4.addElement(playerDelete);
            }

            //add a new player from text input
            var newPlayer:XML = <player></player>;

            newPlayer.@name = myTextBox.text;

            playerData.appendChild(newPlayer);

            myPlayerLabel.text = newPlayer;

        }

        public function deletePlayer():void {
            delete playerData.players.player;

            //not sure of the right syntax for deleting a node but I think this is right?
        }

        public function decrementScore(e:MouseEvent):void {
            myScore--;

            myScoreLabel.text = String(myScore);
            if(myScore == 0) {

                myDecScore.enabled = false;
                myDecScore.alpha = .5;
            }
            trace(myScore);
        }

        public function incrementScore(e:MouseEvent):void {
            myScore++;

            myScoreLabel.text = String(myScore);
            trace(myScore);

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a little hard to follow.

I see the following possible errors:

- a `myPlayerLabel` which seems to never be added to the displaylist. (There is no `addElement(myPlayerLabel)`)
- a `playerLabel` which is added to the displaylist but its `text` is never set. (There is no `playerLabel.text = "a string"`)
- you're assigning an entire XML object to `myPlayerLabel.text`, not its `name` attribute.

Besides these mistakes, I see no good reason why all of this should be written in ActionScript. Your code would be a lot more transparent if those Buttons and Labels were simply instantiated in MXML.

Comment: The problem I had putting them in MXML was that they would always be displayed. I need them to be on the stage when a player is added and not there when one is not. I didnt know another way to do that.

Comment: I also couldn't add the public variables to the groups and have them stay in all groups. Say I added the buttons and such to group1, then I clicked add player again to add a second player to the second group. The player's buttons would jump from group1 to group2, not stay in both. That is also why I had to make new variables inside the function which work for some reason.

Comment: And as for the playerLabel, it is supposed to pull from an XML document that has players already in it, but I am not very familiar with my XML yet so there is another issue.

Comment: Encapsulate the "player field" (currently those HGroups) in a separate class. This class has two states, something like "withPlayer" and "noPlayer". Include the player graphics only the "withPlayer" state.